# return из функции класса возвращает <bound method Class.method of <Class object at 0x...>

Tags: python, python-3.x

Приветствую

Изучаю Python недавно, так что возможно глупый вопрос

Есть некий класс с методами которые возвращают некие значения, но вместо самих значений return возвращает следующее: `<bound method Class.method of <Class object at 0x047975F0>`

Как это исправить?

Заранее спасибо

Comment: Если коротко, поставить скобочки. Приведите пример со строчкой return, на которую ругается интерпретатор и определение того, что Вы возвращаете

Comment: Спасибо, действительно забыл про скобочки при вызове)